# SQL bundle product manipulation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-manipulation

In my company we sell bundles of products that are made up from a mix of different products. The cogs (Cost of Goods Sold) of the individual products (product_sku) change over time, as a consequence the cogs of the bundle will change to.

I need to write an SQL query capable of getting,from the historical value of the products cogs, the total cogs of a bundle over time. The tocal cogs of a bundle is the sum of the cogs of the products multiplied by the quantity in the corresponding timeframe.

A bundle may be made of 2 or more products differents products with different quantities of them.
Bundle examples: (1xA|1xB, 1xA|1xB|2xC, 1xA|2xB|1xC|2xD...)

The products change price without following any pattern, any combination is possible.

Here there is an example of possible bundle I may encounter:

Input table:

| Bundle | quantity | product_sku | COGS | valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1xA|1xB | 1 | A | 3 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-01-01 |
| 1xA|1xB | 1 | B | 4 | 2021-01-01 | 2023-01-01 |
| 1xA|1xB | 1 | A | 6 | 2020-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1xA|1xB | 1 | B | 5 | 2014-01-01 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1xA|1xB | 1 | A | 2 | 2014-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |

And this is what I would like to get:

Output table:

| Bundle | COGS | valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1xA|1xB | 7 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-01-01 |
| 1xA|1xB | 10 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1xA|1xB | 11 | 2020-01-01 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1xA|1xB | 7 | 2014-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |

I don't really know how to approach this problem. I am stuck with the input table. I have tried using window functions, I have tried using conditions with the dates but the outcome is always unsuccessful....

The main problem I have is with the undetermined number of products that a bundle can have, and its making me doubt if this is even achievable in SQL.

Any ideas of how could I do this? Any function I am not aware of? I think the answer lies in using window functions but I don't really know how.

Answer (score 0):

I was able throught a CROSS JOIN to solve the bundles with 2 products, but I still can't find a generic solution for bundles with 3 or more products....

```
SELECT 
  o.bundle_sku,
  o.quantity * o.cogs + s.quantity*s.cogs as Cogs,
  GREATEST(o.dbt_valid_from,  s.dbt_valid_from) dbt_valid_from,
  LEAST(o.dbt_valid_to,  s.dbt_valid_to) dbt_valid_to,

FROM test_table o CROSS JOIN test_table s
WHERE o.sku != s.sku 
AND o.dbt_valid_to > s.dbt_valid_from 
AND o.dbt_valid_to <= s.dbt_valid_to
ORDER BY o.dbt_valid_from DESC
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).